# How to use CapsLock as modifier key without consuming Alt+Shift keybinding?

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

I want to use <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> as a modifier key to type symbols like `({\})=` using the alphabetical keys in the keyboard.

For example:

```
CapsLock+a is mapped to =
CapsLock+k is mapped to \
```

To do this, I mapped <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> using Keyremap4Macbook following the instructions in "[A Useful Capslock Key](http://brettterpstra.com/2012/12/08/a-useful-caps-lock-key/)".

```
<item>
    <name>F19 to F19</name>
    <appendix>(F19 (capslock) to (shift+opt))</appendix>
    <identifier>private.f192f19_escape</identifier>
    <not>VIRTUALMACHINE</not>
    <autogen>
        --KeyOverlaidModifier--
        KeyCode::F19,
        KeyCode::OPTION_L,
        ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L,
    </autogen>
</item>
```

Note that, before that I mapped <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to key code 80 in PcKeyboardHack which is key code of F19.

Then I mapped key combinations of `CapsLock + alphabetical characters` to symbols such as `=\})(` using Ukelele.

So far, everything works properly except that there is a side effect of this setup: I cannot use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> modifier for any other key binding. This is pretty restrictive compromise.

I tried mapping <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to more complex key bindings such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>. But these didn't work well because then mapping <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>+`alphabetical keys` in Ukelele changes the alphabetical keys too. For example, assume that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> is mapped to `=`. Then <kbd>a</kbd> alone is mapped to `=` as well.

I wonder if this problem can be solved somehow? I think there might be two alternative paths to look for solution:

1. Creating a new custom modifier key for <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> without consuming existing modifier keys such as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>.
2. Preventing the mapping of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to change the <kbd>a</kbd> key all together.

Are these solutions possible to implement?

Comment: I just realized I never hit caps lock by purpose...

Comment: Most people don't use caps lock neither. But the location of caps lock is much easier to access than any other modifier key. Using home row keys together with caps lock in order to type symbols is a very big productivity gain.

Comment: Can't you just do the Ukelele part without first mapping caps lock to option + shift?

Answer (score 1):

Got this all from more recent [Brett Terpstra](http://brettterpstra.com/contact/) posts, so full credit to him.

Using [Karabiner Elements](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) and [BetterTouchTool](https://www.boastr.net), you can create a "Hyper" key mapped to control-option-shift-command (which probably won't be used by any apps as a default modifier). Then you can use BetterTouchTool to maps Cap Locks + "a" to type "=". Typing "a" by itself still gets the letter "a". You can also set it up that tapping Cap Locks alone functions as the escape key or even as standard Caps Lock.

Rather than reposting Brett's code here, I'll link to the post: [A Hyper Key with Karabiner Elements, full instructions](http://brettterpstra.com/2017/06/15/a-hyper-key-with-karabiner-elements-full-instructions/).

Some screenshots to help guide you along:

[image: Karabiner Elements Complex Modifications Pane]
After adding Brett's code to karabiner.json, the *Complex Modifications* pane will look like so. No need to do anything else here.

[image: Keyboard Pane of BetterTouchTool]
In BetterTouchTool, switch to the *Keyboard* pane, add a shortcut, type Caps Lock + character, then choose "Insert/Type/Paste Custom Text" as the Trigger Predefined Action.

[image: Insert/Type/Paste Custom Text Sheet]
In the *Insert/Type/Paste Custom Text* sheet, type the character(s) you want and choose "Insert Text by Typing".

Comment: Didn't realize how old this question was. It showed up on the first page of one of the sort options.